# show/hide with dynamic id out of a sql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Submenu Part

```
        <div id="subnavigation">
            <?php
            $verbindung = mysql_connect("host", "user" , "pw") 
            or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden"); 

            mysql_select_db("db") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");

            $sub_instr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM instrument ORDER BY InstrName");

            while($sub = mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_instr))
            {?>
            <div class="sub-item">
                <p>
                    <button type="button" id="<? echo $sub["InstrID"] ?>" class="submenu-button"><? echo $sub["InstrName"] ?></button>
                </p>
            </div><?
            }?>
        </div>
```

Table Part

```
<div class="content-item">
    <!-- Content-Item 1 !-->
    <? $db_instr="SELECT * FROM instrument ORDER BY InstrName" ; $show_instr=m ysql_query($db_instr); while($row=m ysql_fetch_assoc($show_instr)) {?>
    <table id="<? echo $row[" InstrID "] ?>" border="1" class="hidden">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="6">
                <img border="0" src="<? echo " ../SiteAdministration/ControlCenter/Instr/ ".$row["InstrImage "] ?>" alt="<? echo $row[" InstrName "] ?>" width="400" height="400">
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">Informationen</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <? echo $row[ "InstrName"] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Klanglage:</td>
            <td>
                <? echo $row[ "InstrKlang"] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bauschwierigkeit:</td>
            <td>
                <? echo $row[ "InstrBau"] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Materialkosten:</td>
            <td>
                <? echo $row[ "InstrPreis"] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Infotext:</td>
            <td>
                <? echo $row[ "Infotext"] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <? }?>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.sub-item p button').click(function ()
    {
        var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('table#' + buttonID);
        $('table.hidden').hide();
        $('table#' + buttonID).show();

    });

});
```

The first code example describes how I generated a list of buttons, with the ID from the sql database. So every button has it's unique ID coming from the fitting database entry.

The second code example describes a table generated from database entries, every table gets a unique ID coming from the fitting database entry.

The third code example should get the ID of the button I click, get the table with the same ID as the button, hide all tables and only show the table with the same ID as the button.

The problem is, that it won't show anyting. It just hides all tables...

Just to let you know, I'm completly new to javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique(Now you have a table and button with the same id) so use a data-* attribute in the button to store the target element id.

```
<button type="button" data-target="<? echo $sub["InstrID"] ?>" class="submenu-button"><? echo $sub["InstrName"] ?></button>
```

then in the click handler

```
var buttonID = $(this).data('target');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the whole problem. I thought it will be possible to differ the ID's, if I attach them to different tags. And thank you very much for showing the data attribute to me, this'll help a lot in the future.